# MathQuil API Inclusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, mathquill

MathQuill seems to be particularly hard to include in our project, when  we exactly follow the instructions off their website and we put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="file:///mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill.js"></script>
```

[Our directory layout (the file the above code is in is `landing.ejs`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUwgq.png)
It does not work.[The console errors when running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWTpk.png). We think it is quite likely this is an issue with ejs although we are unsure of this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `<script src="http://localhost/mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill.js"></script>`

Comment: Don't really know what else to comment other than that it doesn't work. It says in the console that it 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' for both the .js and .css file.

Comment: Hmm .. .try `<script src="//localhost/mathquill-0.10.1/mathquill.js"></scrip‌​t>` if that doesn't work then check you server config. in production replace localhost with your domain name

Comment: @Novice: um, do those work for you? Are you running your local development servers as root? I'd suggest you use a port >1024, which you can bind to without root; 8000 is common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually found out the answer myself through a considerable amount of painful trial and error, ultimately the answer was or me to use the mathquill resources in my project in GitHub to create my own CDN using RawGit, I still have no idea why this works, but it does.

Comment: As I pointed out in the other answer, the problem was that you were trying to load MathQuill with `file:///`. By using the RawGit CDN, you're using `http://`.

Comment: This is pretty inconvenient though, right? Do you have to upload the built MathQuill files up to your own custom GitHub repo to use the RawGit CDN from?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ejs or MathQuill, the error message in your console says:

[image: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///]

Is your page able to include any other JS or CSS files via `file:///`? If not, you need to use a local HTTP server, for example `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. (You'll probably also want to use relative URLs to reference MathQuill's files, relative to the page.)

(I'm the maintainer of MathQuill.)